# Is "ciao" equivalent to "hello" and "goodbye" in English?

Tags: meaning, spoken-english

I'm from Vietnam, and I'm learning English. I remembered someone said "Ciao" to me once.  I wondered if they could speak Vietnamese since "Ciao" is the same as "Chào" in Vietnamese.

After that, he explained to me that "Ciao" can also be used in English conversation, it is the same as saying "hello" or "goodbye"...

But my understanding of that conversation may have been flawed since I am still learning.  I also never see "Ciao" in English speaking and writing.

Can we use "Ciao" in English? And when can it be used?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's from Italian, and it's a borrowed word in English.

[American Heritage Dictionary "ciao"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ciao)
interjection: Used to express greeting or farewell.

There's a history of the word at that link, which I won't quote here.

It has occasional use in English, though in English conversation it is more commonly used for farewell than as a greeting.

Comment: I'd add that it's a pretty informal word in English, and more likely to be used to say goodbye than hello (though both are possible).

Comment: Also note that it's pronounced the way it's pronounced in Italian.

Comment: @Katy - I agree that it more often "goodbye" than "hello". I'd also add that it's not just very informal, but that some people in the US may perceive it as pretentious. It's sometimes interpreted as implying, "I am a well-traveled person who knows how they say goodbye in Europe!"

Comment: I agree that it's usually used for "goodbye", but in the set phrase "ciao bella" it means "hello".

Comment: In fact, this word is actually kind of rare, at least in a big fraction of the US.  It does exist and is understood, but it is *not* common.  As was mentioned, it's very informal, and I would add that it *at least can be* perceived of as feminine.  Slightly different nuances in usage may potentially exist though, depending on the region/country.  Just be aware that this word can be perceived as *too* casual or potentially feminine.

Comment: As a side note, many languages, presumably including Italian, have a single greeting expression that can be used for both greeting and farewell, typically of an informal character. Another side note could be that a fairly large portion of modern English, especially involving informal/slang expressions, has been adopted from other languages. I suspect that "ciao" is a very common greeting word in a considerable number of languages because its variations appear at least all over Europe.

Answer (score 2):

"Ciao" is a loan word from Italian. There's a lot of languages with a "hello" and/or "goodbye" that are used or at least recognized by English speakers: Spanish, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Hawaiian, Russian, Hindi.

English-speaking, or at least American culture, is rather pluralistic and open to people using their own greetings. In a lot of situations, greeting people with, say, "xin chào" is fine; even if they aren't familiar with the greeting, they'll generally figure it out from context, and many people will appreciate being exposed to another culture. They might try to say it back to you, but likely not get the tones right. And if you say "chào chị" to a woman, she might say that back to you.